# Detect if connection has been dropped

Tags: c++, c++11, tcp

I'm trying to detect when a connection has been dropped.

On this way, it only detects that the connection is no longer active when the internet is back, but not when it has been dropped actually.

```
int loop = 1;
long int msConn;

// Main thread
void connect() {
  // ...

  while (loop) {
    if ((sizeBytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0)) == -1) {
      cout << "Error: connection lost." << endl;

      sleep(15);
      connect();
      return;
    }

    // Update timestamp
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    msConn = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
  }
}

// Heartbeat thread
void checkConnection() {
  for(;;)  {
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;

    if (msConn != 0) {
      if ((ms - msConn) >= 10000) {
        msConn = 0;
        close(sockfd);
      }
    }

    sleep(15);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is a "dropped" connection? I only know a closed connnection.

Comment: @harper I mean a broken connection. For example, the client lost the connection to the internet or the server is shut down.

Comment: TCP/IP works at too high a level to know when the connection is dropped. It only knows that there's no data coming across.

Comment: @MarkRansom But Linux detects a disconnection after 2 hours, right? That's the default value of keep-alive I found.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll it just sets a timeout and assumes the connection is broken if the timeout happens. That's the standard way of detecting the problem, and it's outside of the scope of TCP/IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recv()` returns -1 on error (such as the connection being lost unexpectedly), **0 on graceful disconnect (which you are ignoring!)**, and >0 for data successfully read.  Change your loop to handle the case when `recv()` returns 0, otherwise your loop will not exit when the peer intentionally drops the connection on its end:

```
while (loop) {
    sizeBytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);
    if (sizeBytes == -1) {
        cout << "Error: connection lost." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        sleep(15);
        return;
    }

    if (sizeBytes == 0) {
        cout << "Connection disconnected by peer." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        sleep(15);
        return;
    }

    // Update timestamp
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    msConn = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
}
```

With that said, if the connection is lost abnormally, it may take the OS a long time to detect that condition.  You are implementing your own timeout to account for that, but if you are using the socket in blocking mode (the default behavior), it may take `recv()` a long time to exit (and thus can block your loop from exiting in a timely manner).  You can use `select()`/`epoll()`, or `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO)`, to avoid that.

Comment: Under what conditions can you expect a graceful disconnect? I wouldn't expect to get that when there's a failure.

Comment: A graceful disconnect occurs when the peer closes the connection on its end.

Comment: :S I thought `recv` returned 0 when there's nothing to read. Didn't know that meant disconnected.

Comment: @Brandon: Read the documentation for your platform, eg: [recv(2) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv): **"The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown"**, [recv function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121.aspx): **"If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero"**, etc...  If there is nothing to read, `recv()` will block if running in blocking mode, or will return a `(WSA)EWOULDBLOCK` error if running in non-blocking mode.